# Jquery change image when a divs are hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

I have a hover behavior that works fine in my test => https://jsfiddle.net/5ctav8rx/ but doesn't work in unbounce. My JS code is below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".title-para").hover(function() {
    const imageId = $(this).attr("data-image");

    $(".active-image").removeClass("active-image").hide();
    $("#" + imageId).addClass("active-image").show();

    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).find(".title").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.image-container img {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-container .active-image {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300/28d6ca/bd1717" id="image1" class="active-image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300/d62828/bd1717" id="image2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300/ecff19/bd1717" id="image3">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300/190eed/bd1717" id="image4">
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="title-para" data-image="image1">
    <h3 class="title active">Div Title 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="title-para" data-image="image2">
    <h3 class="title">Div Title 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="title-para" data-image="image3">
    <h3 class="title">Div Title 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="title-para" data-image="image4">
    <h3 class="title">Div Title 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Looking for other methods and ideas of executing the same behavior.

Considering this table below as a guide. When a div is hovered, the corresponding image with the same index as the div shows while other images are hidden. Example when div2 is hovered, image2 shows while images 1,3,4 are hidden. On the initial load, image 1 shows while other images are hidden. Divs remain constant. Maybe a font color change when a div is hovered.

| IMAGE | DIV |
| --- | --- |
| image1, image 2, image3, image4 | div1 |
|  | div2 |
|  | div3 |
|  | div4 |

Comment: FYI: `.hover` without an handlerOut is just a `mouseenter` event.

Comment: *doesn't work in unbounce* - where's the debounce code that doesn't work?  Your code seems to work fine as provided.